# calculate gradient for Contrastive loss

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I have come across this loss function

```py
L = y*d**2 + (1-y)*max(margin-d,0)**2
```

is it possible to calculate the gradient of this type of loss with max function in the function, if yes how should it be done?

I tried finding the gradient for simpler function in numpy and was successful in it , but with this i dont seem to understand how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

On high level yes, there is nothing too special about pointwise maximum, since

```
d/dx max(x, a) = 1 if x>a
                 0 otherwise
```

in your case a=0 and it is nothing but relu that is widely used in deep learning these days.

### CS approach

Lets just use `jax`

```
import jax
from jax import numpy as jnp

def loss(d, y, m):
  return y*d**2 + (1-y)*jnp.maximum(m-d, 0)**2

loss_grad = jax.grad(loss)
```

### Math approach

We can just compute it analytically

[image]